# Property info's GetAccessors method returning IsVirtual for non-virtual property

Tags: c#, reflection

I have this class:

```
public class Model : IModel
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

public interface IModel
{
    int Id {get; }
}
```

I get the property info as follows:

```
var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
var property = properties[0];

var isVirtual = property.GetAccessors()[0].IsVirtual;
```

`isVirtual` is `true`. Why does happen even though the property is not explicitly marked as virtual?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably checking `IsVirtual` against interface IModel. Hence, it is returning true. This is because:

> The accessor of an interface property does not have a body. Thus, the purpose of the accessors is to indicate whether the property is read-write, read-only, or write-only.

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64syzecx.aspx)

Also, if look into IL Code, you would see

For Interface:

```
.method public hidebysig newslot specialname abstract virtual 
    instance int32  get_Id() cil managed
```

For Class:

```
.method public hidebysig newslot specialname virtual final 
            instance int32  get_Id() cil managed
```

Note the `final` in IL (or Sealed in C#), this prevents derived class overriding the interface method. If you explicitly mark the method as virtual, the compiler marks the method as virtual (and no final) allowing a derived class to override the interface method. Thus, Virtual in signature is way the run time provides polymorphic behavior and more like implementation details.

So, If you check IsVirtual against class Model, it would return false.

Comment: I'm checking against `Model` because `T` is the concrete class. Also, the the properties returned are those in the `Model` class and not just the one in `IModel`.

Comment: Can you check with Model directly instead of T

Comment: The whole method is an extension for `IEnumerable<T>`. and not for a particular class.